# React infinite scroller - component not functioning if not enough initial items loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm making a Next.js app which pulls many book objects from a large firestore database, and has a searchbar to filter if the books contain the keyword in their title, category, author, etc. Since I have a lot of books, I'm using lazy loading, but since firebase is stupid and doesn't have good enough free query tools, I can only filter them with the keyword AFTER I pull a limited number of them from my database. I'm using react-infinite-scroller-component to lazily load the results I pull, and then filtering the results like so:

```
// in my render
<InfiniteScroll
  className="my-2 flex flex-col gap-5"
  dataLength={numberLoaded()}
  next={loadMoreSfarim}
  hasMore={checkRemaining()}
  loader={<div>Loading...</div>}
  endMessage={<div>Thats it</div>}>
    {handleFilter(sfarim)}
</InfiniteScroll>

...

function handleFilter(s) {
  let components = s
    .filter((sefer) => filterSefer(sefer))
    .map((sefer) => <SeferEntry key={sefer.id} sefer={sefer} />);
  return components;
}
```

However, if I type in a keyword that only gives a few results, I am unable to scroll as it's not enough results to fill up my window and let me scroll. If I shrink my window so that there's scrolling room, then it works fine. However, I want it to work on large screens too. Has anyone else had this issue? If anyone has a better way to query from firestore for free, that would be greatly appreciated too *(yes, I'm aware of the the `query()` and `where()` from firestore docs, but those aren't enough for checking if multiple fields contain a single keyword as far as I'm aware).*

I have managed to replicate this problem by modifying the codepen from the npm page to use as a minimum working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-scroller-problem-5eduff?file=/src/index.js

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a workaround by adding a useEffect to check if the window is scrollable or not, and then use that to manually call my loading function, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function checkScrollable() {
      const { offsetHeight, scrollHeight, clientHeight } =
        document.documentElement;
      const isContentScrollable = scrollHeight > clientHeight;
      setIsScrollable(isContentScrollable);
      console.log(isContentScrollable);
      if (!isContentScrollable && sfarim.length < totalSfarim) {
        loadMoreSfarim();
      }
    }

    // Check scrollable on component mount and window resize
    checkScrollable();
    window.addEventListener("resize", checkScrollable);

    // Clean up the event listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", checkScrollable);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [sfarim]);
```